# ServiceStack + Swagger ability to group resources differently

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, swagger

Let me start by saying ServiceStack has surpassed all my expectations as a framework. It is amazing what has been accomplished.

I am currently using the Swagger UI plugin with ServiceStack and was wondering is there a way to group resources separately than they appear now? It seems like the grouping is dictated by the root.

The current grouping does something like this:

```
/clients
    /clients/{clientId}/locations/{id} 
    /clients/{clientId}/locations/{locationId}/reports
    /clients/{clientId}/locations/{locationId}/reports/{id}
```

I'd rather have the swagger ui output something that looks like this:

```
Clients
    /clients/{id}
Locations
    /clients/{clientId}/locations
Reports
    /clients/{clientId}/locations/{locationId}/reports
```

It would be cool if you could do something like shown above by using a grouping as shown below.

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}", "GET", 
Summary = @"Says ""Hello"" to provided Name with GET.", 
  Notes = "Longer description of the GET method which says 'Hello'", 
  // like this!
  SwaggerGroup="Clients")]
```

This might be more of a limitation of Swagger and not a limitation of ServiceStack but I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) doesn't make any modifications to the [Swagger UI](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/). If this feature does not exist in Swagger it wont be available in ServiceStack either.

That said the Swagger UI is generated with static JavaScript and HTML in the [/swagger-ui folder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/content/swagger-ui) so you're able to modify the UI and add any customizations you need in your local copy.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that :(. BackboneJs is not a friendly framework (imho). Wish there was a KnockoutJs or Angular version of swagger. Thanks Demis.